# convert words to certain Strings using Haskell

Tags: html, haskell, input, output

I want to read a String line by line. Then put it back into a single String

```
 unlines.map function.lines
```

Now I want to convert any words within the Line.

This * is an example * of a Sentence that I want to convert.

"is an example" is surrounded by single * so this String would be converted to italics using the emphasis tag. how would I write the code for this? The code already reads the String Line by Line. So now I want to convert a String within the Line if it meets the conditions.

Thanks

Comment: Well, what words do you need to convert?

Comment: basically the program takes in any txt input. So ANY word that has * on both sides.. ex: This *sentence* is in the input.txt file. Several conversions to do. A word that has a * on both sides, and a word surrounded by 2 ** such as **word** <- markdown makes this bold in the comment, but I hope that was clear.

Comment: Just in case this is not merely a programming exercise: pandoc exists and is pretty good.

Comment: @Amateur_Haskell: Well, it's clear, but to what extend do **you want to use it**? \*\* can be used to print _multiple_ words with bold face. If you want to support that, you cannot use `map`. If you constraint markdown highlighting to single words, it's almost trivial. Either way, you should include additional information in the question, not in comments.

Comment: IS there a REASON why you PUT single words IN FULL UPPER CASE? That's just noise. Better make sure that the text is nicely formatted; also, if you don't want markdown to be parsed, use \\*. Beside, I think you can get rid of half the text in your question. While it's sometimes good to see the big picture, ~66% of your post shows your current (non-related) progress before you actually ask your question.

Answer (score 1):

Markdown is hard. In particular, it seems the grammar is ambiguous in places. Consider the following:

> The first calculation is 2 * 5, the second calculation is 3 * 7, so deal with it.

Should the text in the middle be in bold? Probably not what the user intended, but if you interpret the spec *literally*...

---

Is there a reason why

```
convertToHTML :: String -> String
convertToHTML [] = [] --prevents calling head on empty line
convertToHTML x
  | doubleHash x     == True     = "<h2>" ++ drop 2 x ++ "</h2>"
  | head x           == '#'      = "<h1>" ++ tail x ++ "</h1>"
  | x                == "---"    = "<hr/>"
  | otherwise                    = x
```

instead of just

```
convertToHTML :: String -> String
convertToHTML cs0 =
  case cs0 of
    ('#':'#':cs) -> "<h2>" ++ cs ++ "</h2>" -- Swapped now.
    (    '#':cs) -> "<h1>" ++ cs ++ "</h1>"
    "---"        -> "<hr/>"
    _            -> cs0
```

which doesn't require any auxiliary functions? (And doesn't require `head`.)

---

What is your *actual question*? How to process star to bold? How about something like this?

```
not_bold :: String -> String
not_bold ('*':cs) -> "<b>" ++ bold cs
not_bold (  c:cs) -> c : not_bold cs
not_bold (    []) -> []

bold :: String -> String
bold ('*':cs) -> "</b>" ++ not_bold cs
bold (  c:cs) -> c : bold cs
bold (    []) -> error "unterminated bold section"
```

Comment: Well the case cs0 of the patterns overlap. when I try to print the line starting with a single # it prints the line with a H1 tag. it also prints the next line that starts with a ## with an h1 tag. So just flip the first 2 patterns. THat should solve that. Thank You! But I kind of clarified my thinking in my question.

Comment: would it be possible to plug in another pattern for the words surrounded by *??

Comment: maybe something like ('asterik' : _ : 'asterik' : cs) -> printstatement

Comment: Not unless you know exactly how many characters are in-between. Otherwise you need to _search_ for them, as per my example.

Comment: To clarify: `'*' : _ : '*' : cs` matches `"*x*"` and `"*K*` but doesn't match `*abc*`.

Comment: I see, I've been trying to find some kind of function to take any amount of characters in-between to convert to a print statement. I've tried any, and elem. just to return some booleans, but what could I use if I just want to say take whatever is in between the asteriks and print that as our other patterns printed.

Comment: also just for some knowledge, lets say I did know the amount of characters in between... so for abc. how would I say okay theres three characters in between so print.

Comment: Honestly, I think you would probably be better off learning a real parsing library. The `bold` / `not_bold` functions I listed above will do literally what you asked for, but as you try to add more and more parsing rules, you're eventually going to end up with an unmaintainable tangle of code that never quite works right. Parsec is the usual suggestion.

Comment: *"Markdown is hard. In particular, it seems the grammar is ambiguous in places."*: [Amen](http://commonmark.org/).